# how to show own header text instead of email prefix by using PHP Mail function?

Tags: php

I want to show **own text** instead of **prefix of email** (no_reply). for example in below image you can see it's showing wordpress not there email prefix. i am using php mail function to send mail so is there any way to do this.

[image: Mail Label example]

[image: Required Mail label example]

[image: Mail Box example]

```
    $to = "$m_email";
    $subject = "PCBMagic Order $order_id Placed Successfully";
    $from = 'no_reply@pcbmagic.com';
     
    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
     
    // Create email headers
    $headers .= "From: $from";
     
    // Compose a simple HTML email message
    
    $message = " hi ";
    // Sending email
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `$from` email address from:

```
$from = 'no_reply@pcbmagic.com';
```

to:

```
$from = 'My own text <no_reply@pcbmagic.com>';
```

And the "My own text" should show up in your email client.